# Finding the set of all limit points of the given sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find the set $H$ of all limit points of the sequence
$$a_{n}=\frac{2014\cdot2^n+(-3)^n}{n}$$
I know that $\lim a_{n_k} = \infty$, where $n_{k}=2k$.

And I know that $\lim a_{n_k} = -\infty$, where $n_{k}=2k+1$.

How do I show that there are no other limit points, so that $H=\{-\infty, \infty\}$.

Comment: You can show that $|a_n|\to\infty$ - that will imply that there are no other limit points.